# Javascript to inject HTML with if statement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function that shows and hide a div through javascript injection. The function injects perfectly without the if (condition) like such: `$("#video-container").load("include/video.html");` but fails to inject properly with the if statement. How does an if statement breaks something like this?

```
var show_video_feed_bool = false;
function show_video_feed() {
    if (show_video_feed_bool == false) {
        $("#video-container").load("include/video.html");
        show_video_feed_bool = true;
    }
    if (show_video_feed_bool) {
        document.getElementById("video-container").innerHTML = "";
        show_video_feed_bool = false;
    }
}
```

video.html

```
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(function (stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch(function (err0r) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Go through it stop by step. `if (show_video_feed_bool == false)`, then you set it to `true`. **Then you check again `if (show_video_feed_bool)`, which yes, now it is, and you undo your changes.** You'll want to use an `else`…

Comment: You’re looking for `if(!show_video_feed_bool){`…`} else {`…`}`, though flipping the order is [recommended](//eslint.org/docs/rules/no-negated-condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```js
show_video_feed_bool = false;
function show_video_feed() {
    if (!show_video_feed_bool) {
        $("#video-container").load("include/video.html");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("video-container").innerHTML = "";
    }
    show_video_feed_bool = !show_video_feed_bool;
}
```